# How to use eval() function with a list of variables?

Tags: python, eval

I have a list of functions as strings:

```
["y + x + 3", "x**2 + y**2 - 17"]  # 2 functions in list
```

I have a list of `Sympy Symbol` objects (basically variables) whos `.name` attribute cooresponds to the variables names in the function strings:

```
[Symbol(x), Symbol(y)]
# list element 0's .name attribute is "x"
```

I found that Python have a neat function called `eval()` which can evaluate strings, for example:

```
x = 1
eval("x + 3") # Result should be 4
```

Basically this is what I want to do with my functions strings. However, since this is a dynamic implementation I don't have variables defined on a line above `eval()` in my program, they are in a list instead. For example, in the example above x is defined as 1, so then the `eval()` function can use it.

But I have my variables in a list, not defined as a variable in the scope of my function. **How could I use the `eval()` function and utilize my list of variables?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` takes local variables as third argument([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)),
so you can do this:

```
from sympy import Symbol
zs = [Symbol('x'), Symbol('y')]
eval('x+y', None, dict([z.name, z] for z in zs))
```

However, maybe you should use [parse_expr](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) which is part of SymPy.

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
zs = [Symbol('x'), Symbol('y')]
parse_expr('x+y', local_dict=dict([z.name, z] for z in zs))
```

Comment: I'll take a look at the parse_expr method. Right now I have it working with eval() with your advice. But maybe the other one it better.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, and you can wrap following codes of replacing and eval in your symbol class（through inheriate）.

```
import ast

x = 5
y = 6

function_str = "y + x + 3"
function_str = function_str.replace('x', '{x}')
function_str = function_str.replace('y', '{y}')

print(ast.literal_eval(function_str.format(x=x, y=y)))
# 14
```

Always remember that using eval is "EVAL" 'cause you should not trust the string passed in, listeral_eval is safer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at full definition of [`eval (expression[, globals[, locals]])`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/eval.html)

You can substitute `globals`/`locals` on `eval`.

E.g.

```
eval("x + 3", {"x":1}) # Result should be 4
```

> How could I use the eval() function and utilize my list of variables?

You have 2 namespaces and you can do everything you want with them.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines:

```
import math

symbols = {'sqrt': math.sqrt, 'x': 5, 'y': 6}

func_strings = ["y + x + 3", "x**2 + y**2 - 17", "sqrt(1764)"]

for expression in func_strings:
    result = eval(expression, {'__builtins__': None}, symbols)
    print('{} -> {}'.format(expression, result))
```

Output:

```
y + x + 3 -> 14
x**2 + y**2 - 17 -> 44
sqrt(1764) -> 42.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do it in my opinion would be to add all of the variables to `locals`. Then you can reference them by name in `eval`. Example:

```
symbols = [Symbol(x), Symbol(y)]
locals().update({symbol.name:symbol for symbol in symbols})

eval("x+y") # Should return the value of x+y
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) clearly states that the dictionary `locals()` returns should no be updated because doing so is unreliable.